# Listen change in a variable in Marionette object?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Which event method can help to capture a change to a value set to 'variable' defined in marionette object.

e.g:

```
var LoginModule = Marionette.Object.extend({

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.state = 'pending';
    },

    init: function(model) {
        model.fetch({validate:true})
        .done(function() {
            this.state = 'success';
        })
        .fail(function(res){
            console.log(res);
            this.state = 'failed';
        });

        return model;
    }
});
```

Here I want to detect change to variable `this.state`. Is there is option to fire once, like listeToOnce?

Usage:

`var loginM = new LoginModule();
loginM.init(model);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
I guess i found better solution for you. Try like below.
Firstly, change your init method like this.

```
init: function(model) {
        model.fetch({validate:true})
        .done(function() {
            this.state = 'success';
            this.triggerMethod('state:changed');
        })
        .fail(function(res){
            console.log(res);
            this.state = 'failed';
            this.triggerMethod('state:changed');
        });

        return model;
    }
```

After that you could catch event `state:changed` like below:

```
this.on("state:changed", function(){
     //handle your changed state
});
```

Comment: Thanks @vlad. when I bind like below, the callback is not getting fired.

`var loginM = new LoginModule();
loginM.on('change', function () {console.log('changes fired')});
loginM.init(model);`

Is there is any specific reason you find?